# invalid type (list) for variable in R

Tags: r, plm

İ am using this code for panel data analysis with `plm` from package `plm`. This is my code and I am having the error below:

```
library('plm')
summary(verilerrdf)
library(PerformanceAnalytics) #oldu
chart.Correlation(verilerrdf[,6:12], histogram=TRUE, pch=19) #oldu
x <- verilerrd[5:11] #oldu
y1<-verilerrd[,3] #oldu
y2<-verilerrd[,4] #oldu
summary(verilerrdf)
pdata <- pdata.frame(verilerrdf, index = c("bg","tarih")) #oldu
modelhavuz<- y1~ymdc+mev+oz+ynfg+yenf+tdo+gdp #oldu
pooling<-plm(modelhavuz, data=pdata, model="pooling")
```

Error:

```
pooling<-plm(modelhavuz, data=pdata, model="pooling")
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y1'
```

Can you please explain the source of the error?

Comment: We don't have the `verilerrdf` or `verilerrd` variables, so we can't really help here.  Could you put together a reproducible example, e.g. by including enough data so that someone else running your code will see the same error?  It doesn't need to be the whole dataset (and shouldn't be, if it's large); just a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: In your formula `modelhavuz` you want to name variable which are included in your data `pdata`. Likely, this is not the case.